# Wordpress query posts by tag and category

Tags: wordpress, tags, categories

I'm trying to create a set of WP pages with indices to all posts which have tag X as well as category Y.

I found [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4201/how-to-query-posts-by-category-and-tag) which seems to do exactly what I want and I understand how to edit it for each index page, but I don't know where/how to use the actual code to create the index pages.

```
global $wp_query;
    $args = array(
    'category__and' => 'category', 
    'tag__in' => 'post_tag', //must use tag id for this field
    'posts_per_page' => -1); //get all posts

$posts = get_posts($args);
    foreach ($posts as $post) :
//do stuff 
 endforeach;
```

TIA for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what finally worked - note that I needed the category ID but the tag slug.

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

<?php query_posts( 'cat=6&tag=a1&&orderby=title&order=asc' );?>

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>

<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'search' ); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php else : ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You use that code to replace the basic query in the loop in your template.

```
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts
```

Comment: Thank you. If I understand correctly, that would be for my index page, right? I don't want to change the query on my index page; I want to create a set of separate pages: a page with query results of tag X and category Y, a page with query results of tag X and category Z, etc.

Comment: Yes, you could do it on your index page. But you can also do it on any page that runs the loop. Sounds like you want a series of templates, each one with the loop modified to return the posts as appropriate.

Comment: I found a simpler query on the page you gave me, but I'm not getting any results. Any idea what might be wrong?

`<?php
/*
Template Name: A1 Grammar
*/

get_header(); ?>

 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8 content-area" role="main">

<?php
// The Query
query_posts( 'cat=6&tag=69' );

// The Loop
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    echo '<li>';
    the_title();
    echo '</li>';
endwhile;

// Reset Query
wp_reset_query();
?>`

Comment: You're not running all the code together like you pasted it here, right? You need to make sure none of the php code is on a line with "//"  In fact, just take out the "// The Query" "// The Loop" "// Reset Query" comments. And remember that you need to create a page that USES the "A1 Grammar " template.

Comment: Correct - when I pasted it here, it all ran together, and I didn't bother to add all the line breaks back in. And yes, I created a page, but no posts show up: https://www.lawlessfrench.com/verb-conjugations/a1-grammar/

Comment: After much tinkering, I've almost got it. The key is to use the tag slug with the category ID (the opposite of what the original code said to use). The only problem now is that the full posts are showing one after the other, rather than just excerpts.

`<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

<?php query_posts( 'cat=6&tag=a1' );?>

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>

<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php themememe_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>

<?php else : ?>`

Comment: That's b/c ur calling "the_content();" in "content-page.php." The 'content-page.php' file included in your template actually formats the content that gets displayed. You can replace/add/reorder calls like the_title();, the_excerpt();, the_content();, etc. in "content-page.php."